# Simple iFrame does not show some cross domain pages

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe

I am trying to create a site to embed other cross-domain sites (say, to build a browser in a browser). This shall happen locally. I tried with a simple iFrame:

It will work for some pages, but not for others like Facebook and Google. The space will just stay white. I guess this is some sort of security measure of these more sophisticated platforms, but I don't understand, why it's even in their hands.

Do you know why? And, most importantly, how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Google is sending an `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header, which prevents display in cross-domain iframes.

Comment: Is there another way?

Comment: Not sanely. I mean, you could cURL or download the page source, then try to fix it up and display it.